# How can i get my post urn from organisation urn?

Tags: postman, linkedin-api

How can i get my post urn for acessing comments and likes using my organisation urn? Even i have extracted ogranisation page urn it shows me a share urn but tha urn is not displaying any comments or like in my post.
I am expecting to get comments shares of the particular post using post urn but i dont know post urn i only have organisation urn and i want post urn.

I have already tried using get https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A<organisation_id>)&count=100 this request and i got the share urn but with the share urn the post likes and comments are not visible with post urn or activity urn am able to get likes and comments but i dont have post urn.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.